# Is there a way to include the "chromedriver.exe" within a Python program .exe (via pyinstaller)?

Tags: python, selenium, pyinstaller, portability

Hello there to the community. This is my first question, I hope to contribute in the future to help some of you. In the meantime, I was trying to create a simple program. The idea is a currency converter between the dollar and my currency (Argentine pesos). I implemented a web scraper using selenium that uses the chromedriver.exe archive (I'm within Windows).
Afterward, I created a .exe using pyinstaller. The problem is that it works for me because in the program I specify this program path, but the main idea was to make it fully portable, so to pass it to another PC and still work. Could anyone help me with this?
Things that I tried were including the chromedriver.exe in the .zip file that I transfer to the other PC and using a generic path like "C:\dolar" and put all the files in there. But what I really want is just one archive .exe that works.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: This should be a useful page - [Make Python & Selenium program executable (.exe) (How to include webdriver in .exe)](https://www.zacoding.com/en/post/python-selenium-to-exe/)

Comment: @CavinDsouza has the right article

Comment: Thanks a lot. I followed this guy's advice and worked perfectly. Just one detail. Before I was able to compile this in just one .exe, I managed to not show the browser opening (which was a desirable thing). Now, I can create one .exe file BUT the browser is opening, and can't manage that... Any second advice? (for the time being, that's a minor issue, now I can export this .exe to any PC and work! just little problem with antivirus thinking it's a trojan, lol).

Comment: My bad, this didn't work... I'm getting this error while executing the .exe created:

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:64735/devtools/browser/faa489de-7a1f-4d00-b41f-467c856f166b
[10804:16396:0501/140019.900:ERROR:browser_switcher_service.cc(238)] XXX Init()

The web browser opens but then the app crashes. If I run it through the .py file from console it works just fine. This is giving me headaches.

Comment: @GustavoKildegaard if you're using chromedriver.exe, you should pass this argument `--headless` to your chrome_options, that ensures that the browser window does not pop up. Keep your .exe file in a specific folder and add an exclusion rule to your antivirus for that folder. That should stop the unnecessary delays and false positives.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea --add-binary of pyinstaller and then inside your script to use sys._MEIPASS - it will point to the temporary folder with unpacked  files.

From my project:

```
 def resource_path():
        if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
            return os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, 'media')
        else:
            return ''
```

So when I run it without pyinstaller I assume that required files are in the current folder.